# Filter list generated with ng-repeat by md-tabs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

next question (sorry, I really try to code, but at the moment I don't understand everything).

I have a list with checkboxes which is generated with ng-repeat.
Above I have a tab navigation which I want to use as a filter.

I tried something like this (in many variations) but it doesn't work:

```
 <span ng-repeat="item in items | filter: item.category: cat.category">
```

My exceptation is that on tab Category1, only bullhorn, car and star are shown, Category2 only euro, eye and facebook and tab Category3 only fax, feed and film are shown.

Now there are all items from the scope, not filtered after category.

Heres a plnkr example with my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/iCQRwH4XRr3DKQcQG329

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Should explain what you expect this to do...and what it is doing differently than expected. Also how we should use demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to filter your Array with the `cat` Object, so you just add the Object witch you want to use to filter (look at the [Docmentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) > expression > Object):

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items | filter: cat.category">
```

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/klosFzpS3oU6kkh92fd4?p=preview)

Comment: OMG, is it really so easy? :D
Thinkin way too complicated, thanks man!

Comment: No Problem. Really look at the Documentation it explains it really well.

Comment: Got it know!
Yes I try to read the docs, but I'm totally new to code and those confuse me sometimes ;)